# Painting multiple objects at different times in the most efficient manner

Tags: java, animation, awt, paint

So I have an assignment where I have to create a "game" type application in which there are multiple moving objects (definately over 10) and some are triggered by user KeyEvents.
I seem to understand the concept but I have a question. How do I draw all objects (which animate up and down) and include KeyEvents so they all perform at once, and don't go in a linear sequence. I looked up multi-threading for this but I highly doubt it would be a good idea as I feel this can be done with only 1 thread.

Any feedback or ideas would be greatly appreciated. Thanks! :)

An example of what I mean is:

```
public void onPaint(Graphics g){
g.draw(apple);
g.draw(character);
moveCharacter(g);
moveApple(g);
}
```

So here, I have to first move the character, then the apple, how can I do both of them at the same time? Except with multiple objects.

Comment: What do you mean when you say "perform at once, and don't go in a linear sequence"? Also don't worry about efficiency unless you're dealing with thousands of objects. Multi-threading is most definitely overkill, and the graphics surface does not support concurrent drawing anyway.

Comment: @ZongZhengLi I think he's referring to concurrent drawing of the objects, rather than drawing them sequentially as the code shows.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Ideally you will want to separate your actual game logic from the rendering. Do the calculations, moving, etc on a separate thread from the draw thread. There are some subtle complications that may arise from this relating to concurrency, but it's still a good idea.

It's not clear what you mean by "do both at the same time", but the code should execute so fast that it may as well be at the same time. What you want to avoid is having having any sort of blocking in the methods (eg. user input).

Comment: Thanks, I think I understand what you mean. So are you saying that I should create two threads, one which is for the onPaint method and the others for "behind-the-scenes" part?

Comment: Exactly. That is how most games/realtime applications do it.